# В чем разница между промисами и async await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise, ecmascript

Я не понимаю почему лучше использовать async/await вместо промисов (Promise).

Что это дает?

Можете объяснить?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Синтаксис async/await позволяет нам работать с асинхронным кодом так, как будто мы работаем с синхронным.**

Рассмотрим простой пример, где некая функция возвращает нам [промис](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) с которым мы можем взаимодействовать:

```
const getUserData = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("данные"), 1000))
}
```

Если мы воспользуемся [методами класса Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Instance_methods), то получим результат:

```
const parentFunction = () = > {
  // ... делаю дела
  // теперь мне нужны данные с удаленного сервера
  getUserData().then(data => {
     // получила данные
     // ... что то делаю с этими данными     
  })
}
```

где можно увидеть зарождающуюся вложенность, котороя будет только возрастать при усложнении нашей логики и ее зависимости от других асинхронных запросов.

Однако мы может решить этот момент, если воспользуемся [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const parentFunction = async () = > {
  // ... делаю дела
  // теперь мне нужны данные с удаленного сервера
  const data = await getUserData() // получила данные
  // ... что то делаю с этими данными     
}
```

Данный синтаксис особенно удобен при сложных сценариях, вместе с [циклами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), конструкциями типа [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) и т.д.

А так же никакого [Promise Hell'a](https://medium.com/@ringgagustavino/avoid-promise-hell-6d9a518aea8c).

Comment: «вложенность, котороя будет только возрастать» — промисы для того и придумали, чтобы вложенность не возрастала. А «Promise Hell» смахивает уже на какую-то банальную некомпетентность и непонимание базовых принципов работы промисов

Comment: Довольно интересно как у Вас получиться избежать этого при обработке множества асинхронных вызовов внутри одной функции где последующие зависят от предидущих, не говоря уже что у каждого еще может быть catch, finally, etc.

Comment: Через then, catch и Promise.all всё это отлично делается (через await конечно удобнее, но промисы всё же не так плохи)

Comment: примеры кода не равнозначны.

Comment: @Grundy можете пояснить?

Comment: @Ivy, в примере с promise не возвращается ничего, а в примере с await - возвращается. Если в первом примере тоже возвращать, то then выносится за функцию и никакой вложенности не добавляется

Answer (score 7):

Некорректно сравнивать [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) и [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), так как любая `async` функция возвращает тот же самый `Promise`.

Таким образом - они ничем не отличаются.

По сути `await` просто удобная запись для `then`.

```
var res1 = await asyncFun();
var res2 = await res1.nextFun();
console.log(res2);
```

аналогично

```
asyncFun()
    .then(res1 => res1.nextFun())
    .then(res2 => console.log(res2));
```

Поэтому, что именно использовать и в каких случаях может зависеть только от договоренностей внутри команды.

---

Также стоит упомянуть про работу с циклами.

`await` позволяет упростить запись, если каждая итерация цикла должна ждать завершение какой-то асинхронной операции, однако, если итерации запускают независимые асинхронные функции - то `await` ничем не поможет. И для ожидания всех запущенных операций можно воспользоваться [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)